# md5/hash on vb6?

Tags: vb6, hash, md5

I'm making a program that has a login. Is there any way to encrypt the normal password so that it can't be read in the data base? I've done a trick but I'm not content with it. What I did was to get the first, mid, and last char only and convert each char into ascii. Is there a way to convert all the text into ascii or something like md5/hash in php?

I'm really sorry about this thing, I haven't mentioned that my project is a VB6 project.

Comment: Google search: basMD5.bas "David Ireland"

Comment: Im sorry about the missing info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use MD5 to store hashed passwords! See stuff like http://www.freerainbowtables.com/ for reasons why. MD5 is thoroughly broken... Check what you have available in VB6 (I'm hardly a VB6 guy ;-)) in the realm of cryptography. Something based on (salted) password-based encryption stuff is what you want, Google for "vb6 pbkdf2", I see a lot of hits there :)

Answer (score 1):

I have been using a class by Phil Fresle for generating MD5 signatures for strings. You can copy and paste the source to create the class. To use it in your application I suggest storing the hash rather than the password. The class source code can be found [here](http://files.codes-sources.com/fichier.aspx?id=27271&f=cMD5.cls&lang=en).